# MySQL problem - COMPLETE server overrun! Please advise

Tags: php, optimization, query-optimization, mysql

This is my first question here so please don't be tough on me... :P
I usually tend to google my way to a solution but now I'm in a hurry and have used up all the resources I had...

because my website is a commercial one, it would be fair to go ahead and pay someone to help me but... I have some financial problems myself, this was the 3rd month of payment to my dedicated server, still it was only the first month since my site was actually up... I have made it all by myself because I cannot afford paying anyone, and have no ads on it because I don't think I would be getting anything now and the ads would just be useless...although I intend in using ads later in my site's life, i don't get a dime from the (at least for my budget) expensive server rent... :(

This is my problem:
I have a dedicated server which has been going great until a few days ago when my traffic started going up...for a few days, i keep getting emails from my cpu status monitor from my server...
it's like stuck at full throttle and I'm trying to find out why and repair the problem!...

I'm really desperate so please help me!

here are my latest stats (though they've been like this for like 4 days...)
`08:02:35 up 12 days, 14:39,  0 users,  load average: 25.82, 25.98, 25.92`

I use stat counter, I think they are pretty accurate (the code is on every page so these are my website's global results)...
My stats are:

```
Page Loads  Unique Visits   
10,367              1,843
```

My main pages are `index.php` and `videos.php` (i run a video site btw)

the index and videos.php pages are always using around 140-150-160% of the cpu
i mean huh?
they're using more than 100%? like loaning or what?

what they both do is:
(mainly the videos page, the index is just a simplified version of it)

check -and take if passed- a query and a page number.
query a database, take results from a table and show them

I use `mysql_connect` for everything i take from mysql.
I heard of permanent connections in mysql as being a possible solution to a large number of queries, but also read about a lot of cons to this method caused by security issues...
please advise?

my database is myisam engined
I have 2 main tables: games and videos.
Along them are around 5-6000 tables used for storing comments...

```
 games table:    9   columns    
 id - primary   
 name - fulltext - used by my search    

 videos table:    17 columns    
 indexes:   
 id-primary     
 title,tags-fulltext-used by search
```

the rest of the tables are used for comments but they dont have any index except the id field.
they only keep the comment and the date in themselves.
when i load a search page, all data is taken from the db:
search for keywords, take the most relative and then echo all data related to the matched items.
when opening a video page, all comments from a certain db are loaded and displayed in a box.

what is the best thing I can do to reduce processing power use?

also, my support team just emailed me:

> we have increased the table-cache to 12000 , please check now how it goes .And also it is better to get a my.cnf file which is most suitable to your working environment , here the mysql variables are set to the default values .

I just read something about the `my.cnf` file on google but nothing related to my case...
Could someone please indicate me what should my `my.cnf` file contain? related to my sittuation?

I have my server information here, but it takes some space... how can I close it somehow and you only open if you want to read? without using links?

should i just post it here like this?
Please, if a moderator reads this and can collapse it somehow, please do so!

```
Server Information:
-------------------------------------------------------

Processor Information
Total processors: 6

Processor #1

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB

Processor #2

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB

Processor #3

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB

Processor #4

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB

Processor #5

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB

Processor #6

Vendor
    AuthenticAMD

Name
    AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor

Speed
    2800.000 MHz

Cache
    512 KB


Memory Information

Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin permissible range
Memory: 7917400k/8912896k available (2575k kernel code, 208164k reserved, 1304k data, 212k init)



System Information

Linux nrgysrv1.hostrprv1.com 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:52:25 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Physical Disks

SCSI device sda: 2930277168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1500302 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sda: 2930277168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1500302 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
SCSI device sdb: 2930277168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1500302 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sdb: 2930277168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1500302 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write back
sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sdb
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0



Current Memory Usage

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7920256    7873744      46512          0      61148    6980096
-/+ buffers/cache:     832500    7087756
Swap:      4192956        184    4192772
Total:    12113212    7873928    4239284


Current Disk Usage

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             1.4T  636G  645G  50% /
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
tmpfs                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             1.4T  291G 1016G  23% /backup
/usr/tmpDSK           485M   11M  449M   3% /tmp


----------------------------------------------------
```

I think this is all the information I have.

If you have mercy on me, please help!...
thanks a million billion times!hot

Comment: check the slow query log. Also profile your php code (using xhprof) for example to see what eats the resources. Also, check in top / htop in the shell, which is the process with highest load - if this is php, mysql or apache.

Comment: `Along them are around 5-6000 tables used for storing comments` Wait, what?

Comment: Why do you have 5000+ comments tables?

Comment: so easy answer first - comment tables: i use comment tables to store comments... i'm still looking for a better solution, this one is created by me, and yes, i understand it's really lame... but still... the number is so high because i have around 5000 videos and around 2000 games, from which only around 5000 have comments, thus have a table

Comment: and for the first comment...thanks for the advise... now i just have more stuff to look up on G! :P... comment appreciated, of course! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the index and videos.php pages are always using around 140-150-160% of the cpu i mean huh? they're using more than 100%? like loaning or what?

No, the load is expressed as one unit per CPU, so if your server has four CPUs, a load of 1.00 (or 100%) means that one CPU is at full load and the other three are idling (or two are at 50% load and the other two at 0%, or any similar combination) and a load of 4.00 (or 400%) would mean that all the CPUs are at full capacity.

> I use mysql_connect for everything i take from mysql. I heard of permanent connections in mysql as being a possible solution to a large number of queries, but also read about a lot of cons to this method caused by security issues... please advise?

Why should it be a *security issue*? Maybe it can be a *performance issue* if misused, but definitely not a security issue.

From what you're writing it seems you're quite a novice on relational database and perhaps web development, the first step I suggest is to buy a database book and learn how they work and how to use them, then a good book on PHP. Otherwise, you will be [programming by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) and will never resolve your issues.

By the way, if you're new (and you know it) you should give a read to [the FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: started using the permanent connection for around 4 hours or so... no email about my cpu overloading :D... gonna check my stats soon but hey, thanks a lot!

Comment: and hey... sorry for bragging earlier... it's not my style ... :(

Comment: nope...not good... nothing changed, switched to permanent connection with 500 max connections setting and cpu is still at max... means i'll let my server run like that until after my final exams... i'll have time for it then

Answer (score 3):

First, isolate the problem. There's no point in tuning MySQL if the root cause of the problem is in your php code.

Your support said they "increased the table-cache to 12000", so they probably increased the value for table_open_cache from 400 (default) to 12000. (You probably shouldn't have 6000 tables. Reconsider that design.)

For MySQL, study these sections of the MySQL docs.

[Tuning Server Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-parameters.html)

> When tuning a MySQL server, the two
>   most important variables to configure
>   are key_buffer_size and
>   table_open_cache. You should first
>   feel confident that you have these set
>   appropriately before trying to change
>   any other variables.

[Preconfigured Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html#option-files-preconfigured)

> MySQL provides a number of
>   preconfigured option files that can be
>   used as a basis for tuning the MySQL
>   server. Look for files such as
>   my-small.cnf, my-medium.cnf,
>   my-large.cnf, and my-huge.cnf, which
>   are sample option files for small,
>   medium, large, and very large systems.

[Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)

[Server Status Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html)

You should also have a local or remote system for testing.

Comment: thanks! appreciate any comment! yes, indeed i have a server on my local computer, just have to get the settings updated with the ones on my remote server, i guess... so i think this is homework for next week, after my final exams... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you have a separate table for each video. All the comments (or whatever) should be stored in the SAME table with a video_id or similar attached to them to link them back to the video in question.

Comment: yes,thanks for the suggestion! this is my idea as my videos number is growing big and my mysql stability grows short... i'll probably tune in and change the table structure and php script! thanks again!