# mysql and php FULLTEXT search does more, but doesn't do less?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

Listed on this question:
[MySQL problem - COMPLETE server overrun! Please advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466665/mysql-problem-complete-server-overrun-please-advise)
are all my server details, so I don't have to re-write them here.

So I'm having a PHP script which interacts with a mysql DB.
2 days ago, due to many requests from my users, I have switched from clasic "select * from table where column like 'blabla' and column like 'lablab'" to the fulltext search.
Indexed, tested, good to go.
2 days on the job, already received a bag of complains.

Searches are indeed better, that is if you use full words... :(

try searching for "apple" and you find almost the same results.

try searching for "apple computer at low prices" and the fulltext search is WAY above any LIKE search

try searching for "ple" and you get a full list of results with the classic method... but a big fat "Nothing found" text laying in front of you with the fulltext search...

Sorry for making it sound so poetic up to this point... :|

Is there any workaround for this? making the fulltext use some freakin' wildcards? like %foo% should bring me ffoork, flfooor etc...

And for those of you asking, yeah I don't really know my way around mysql further than syntax, simple expressions and basic functions.

Please help me with a code snippet or link to some method of working this out...
If possible, i would rather not complicate my existence with some 3rd party mysql search engine but as a last resort...

Thank you very much in advance!
Cheers!

Sorry, I forgot to put my code up:

```
$query="SELECT *, 
    CASE when title like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as titlematch, 
    CASE when tags like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as tagsmatch,
    MATCH (title, tags) AGAINST ('".$s."') AS relevance 
    FROM videos  
    WHERE MATCH(title, tags) AGAINST ('".$s."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    HAVING relevance > 0  
    ORDER by titlematch desc, tagsmatch desc, relevance desc, `datetime` desc, `views` desc
    ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using boolean mode, you can update your PHP code to automatically add wildcards around the search string inside of `AGAINST(...)`. This should solve your problem for single-word searches.

You could also add wildcards around each single word in case of multi-word searches, but I'd recommend doing some testing with real data (e.g. commonly searched keywords, if you log them) in order to make sure that current result relevancy is not impacted.

---

**Update:** try the following:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    CASE when title like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as titlematch, 
    CASE when tags like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as tagsmatch,
    MATCH (title, tags) AGAINST ('*".$s."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance

FROM videos

WHERE
    title like '%".$s."%' OR
    tags like '%".$s."%' OR
    MATCH (title, tags) AGAINST ('*".$s."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

ORDER by
    titlematch desc, tagsmatch desc, relevance desc
```

Comment: i already tried using wildcard like this:  AGAINST ('%".$s."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and like this:  AGAINST ('\*".$s."\*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), but all fails when tested.(meaning nothing changes!)... i  tried with both one word or multiple words... is there no hope for me?!... :|

Comment: It works on my small test case. Please try the query above (it had to be modified a bit on top of adding wildcards into `AGAINST(...)`).

Comment: it works absolutely perfect! you are great! thanks a million times!

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use a condition in your PHP search function, and if a single word or few characters were searched, use the good ol' LIKE search?

Comment: thanks for your answer! i will try this as a last resort as another query is not really the most cpu-effective way to deal with my script...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into BOOLEAN fulltext searches.  They allow the use of wildcards and other operators to perform complex fulltext searches.

[MySQL Boolean Fulltext Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

If this doesn't work for you, an alternate solution could be to perform a like search if the fulltext search returns 0 results.

Comment: yeah, as you can see from my edit, i already use the boolean mode... i may try to test for number of results and query if it is 0 but that means an extra query and at the moment i'm already having issues with my cpu use... anyways... thanks for answer!